# Deploying an application server to a server

Tags: wcf, deployment, client-server

I am building a client-server application, this is all running locally on my computer whilst I am developing the system. However, eventually I would like to deploy the server-side part of the application to a server to run 24/7, enabling client applications to connect and consume the service at will. What I would like to know is, when I come to doing this would I simply just install the server-side application on the server, hit run and that's it? That just seems... well not right (to me), is this the way it is done? or is there a lot more to it? I imagine there is, but I can't seem to find any content on this subject.

FYI - the server is a self hosted WCF application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd want to take your program's executable, support dlls and config files and drop them into a folder. Then create a Windows Service to run the program; if you don't use a Windows Service, the program will only run while you're logged on, which isn't good. As a Windows Service, a reboot of the server will bring the program back online even if you're not logged on.

Here's a knowledge base article from MS on how to make a windows service.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251192

If you're program is compiled as a DLL, then create a small .exe program to run it (a wrapper) then deploy the program as described in the article.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you very much! I don't know why some of the simplest answers are the hardest to find, but thanks again =)